# 'react-native-ble-plx' error react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, bluetooth

I want to write a react-native code where I want to get bluetooth data of surrounding devices. There are startScan button and stopScan buttons. These buttons allow us to start and stop scanning. I runnig this code for android but i get this error:

```
This error is located at:
    in App
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in BluetoothProje(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

My code:

```js
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import {
      SafeAreaView,
      View,
      Text,
      Button,
      StyleSheet,
      FlatList,
    } from 'react-native';
    import BleManager from 'react-native-ble-plx';
    
    const App = () => {
      const [devices, setDevices] = useState([]);
      const [scanning, setScanning] = useState(false);
    
      const bleManager = new BleManager();
    
      useEffect(() => {
        // Start the BLE manager when the component is mounted
        bleManager.start();
    
        // Subscribe to device discovery events
        bleManager.onDeviceDiscovered(device => {
          setDevices(prevDevices => [...prevDevices, device]);
        });
    
        return () => {
          // Stop the BLE manager and unsubscribe from events when the component unmounts
          bleManager.stop();
          bleManager.removeAllListeners();
        };
      }, []);
    
      const startScan = () => {
        setScanning(true);
        setDevices([]);
        bleManager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
          if (error) {
            // Handle error
            console.log(error);
          }
          if (device) {
            // Device was discovered
            console.log(device);
          }
        });
      };
    
      const stopScan = () => {
        setScanning(false);
        bleManager.stopDeviceScan();
      };
    
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          {scanning ? (
            <Button title="Stop Scan" onPress={stopScan} />
          ) : (
            <Button title="Start Scan" onPress={startScan} />
          )}
          <FlatList
            data={devices}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <View style={styles.deviceContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.deviceName}>{item.name}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.deviceId}>{item.id}</Text>
              </View>
            )}
          />
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    };
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      deviceContainer: {
        padding: 16,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: '#ccc',
      },
      deviceName: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      },
      deviceId: {
        fontSize: 14,
        color: '#666',
      },
    });
    
    export default App;
```

What can you suggest me to solve this error. Relevant npm packages are already installed.

Answer (score 0):

You create `bleManager` every time you render the application. Change it to:

```js
const [bleManager, setBleManager] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!bleManager) {
    const instance = new BleManager();
    setBleManager(instance)
    instance.start();
  }
  return () => {
          // Stop the BLE manager and unsubscribe from events when the component unmounts
          bleManager.stop();
          bleManager.removeAllListeners();
        };
}, [])
```

Comment: @profundusman if it was helpful mark it as asnwer

Comment: I tried your method but I get the same error where exactly I get the error is "const instance = new BleManager();" So it cannot create a new instance. i tried const,let and var verisons but it didnt work . Do you have any advice you can give me?

Comment: @profundusman do you have another js file in your project? Looks like the error happens in a different place.

Comment: Firstly Thanks your interest and comments sir!  I have just app.js and index.js and deafult react-native files and folders. Also i use react-native-ble-plx libary. I don't think this library is too old updated this year from what I've seen. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ble-plx